# Adding data to a newly added column

Tags: oracle, table, system-databases

I added an extra column to my table and now need to populate it against the data already there.

As a dummy example, I have a table already named customers with `CustomerID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`. I've now added a column called `MobilePhone` and want to populate the final column to match the data already there.

```
CustomerID        FirstName          LastName            MobilePhone
83276432          Joe                Bloggs
48273452          Ava                Avery
26432346          Jack               Jakes
```

How do I populate the MobilePhone column for Joe, Ava and Jack?

I've tried

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS 
(MobilePhone)
WHERE FirstName = 'Joe', 'Ava', 'Jack'
VALUES (07874384243, 07436453264, 07632531627);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can't insert new values into the newly added column in such way.

You can update the newly added column as shown below.

```
SQL> alter table cust add mobile varchar2(10);

Table altered.

SQL> select * from cust;

    ID NAME             MOBILE
---------- -------------------- ----------
     1 joe
     2 jane


SQL> update cust set mobile='9878765346' where id=1;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from cust;

    ID NAME         MOBILE
---------- -------------------- ----------
     1 joe          9878765346
     2 jane
```

If you want to update all records at once, here are some methods you can use one appropriate for you-[ORAFAQ:8 Bulk Update Methods Compared](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2450)